# ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn

Tags: clojure

I have a function that takes the number of years and salary, then recursively doubles the salary until years is exhausted.  However, I keep getting this error:

> ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn

**The Code**

```
(defn calculate-salary
    [years salary]
    (if (= years 0)
        (salary)
        (calculate-salary (- years 1) (* salary 2))))
```

I'm very new to Clojure so I'm sure its something simple, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The error's meaning shouldn't be too hard to sort out: a number is being used where a function is expected.

Parenthesis in Clojure are not a grouping construct, they are used primarily to invoke function calls. If you change `(salary)` to `salary` you will return the number rather than attempting to call it as a no-argument function.

Comment: Right on.  I need to release myself from my imperative heritage!

Comment: Aha thanks for the explanation. The meaning of the parenthesis were also not clear to me. As a side-note, I had the same error because I wrote `(repeatedly (read))` instead of `(repeatedly read)`.

Answer (score 8):

Since you are new I rewrote your function to be a bit more idiomatic.  Also, it uses recur so it will not consume the call stack.

```
(defn calculate-salary
  [years salary]
  (if (zero? years)
    salary
    (recur (dec years) (* salary 2))))
```

Notice the use of the zero? predicate, recur, and dec

EDIT:
typos and grammar

Answer (score 7):

This

```
(salary)
```

is a function call, but `salary` is not a function -- it's a number.

The solution is to not wrap it in parentheses:

```
(if (= years 0) salary (calculate-salary (- years 1) (* salary 2)))
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the brackets from around `salary` in your if condition:

```
(if (= years 0)
        salary
        (calculate-salary (- years 1) (* salary 2))
```

the form `(f arg1 arg2 ..)` attempts to call `f` as a function with `arg1, arg2 ...` as arguments. Therefore `(salary)` attempts to invoke `salary` (a long) as a function with no arguments, hence the error.